# Is there any other way of typing aligned equations aside from cases and align?

Tags: equations

I want to type aligned equations

```
x = a    
y = b
z = c
```

I only know two ways of achieving this. One is using `\begin{align}`, the other is by using `\begin{cases}` wrapped within a `\begin{equations}`.

Is there any other way to achieve aligned equations?

Comment: `align` is the most used one. Your second approach sounds ugly.

Comment: It mostly depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You also have `alignat`, which lets you control the spacing between alignment columns , and `flalign`.

Comment: the amsmath package offers `align`, `flalign`, `alignat`, as top level environemnts, or inside `equation`  `aligned` or `alignedat` depending if you want one equation number or 3. Don't use `cases` for such a display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

align
\begin{align}
x &= a \\
y &= b \\
z &= c  
\end{align}

alignat
\begin{alignat}{1}
x &= a \\
y &= b \\
z &= c  
\end{alignat}

flalign
\begin{flalign}
x &= a \\
y &= b \\
z &= c  
\end{flalign}

equation/aligned
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x &= a \\
y &= b \\
z &= c  
\end{aligned}  
\end{equation}


equation/alignedat
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{1}
x &= a \\
y &= b \\
z &= c  
\end{alignedat}  
\end{equation}

equation/cases
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1 &x = a \\
0 &y = b \\
1 &z = c  
\end{cases}  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

There are more examples in `amsldoc.pdf` (`texdoc amsmath` in texlive)